# Get SUM of product quantity for product 'A' of Company 'XYZ' from database monthwise for whole year

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has product quantity column and the database has multiple entries in a single month. 
For eg: 
Date is in string format as i have used JXDatePicker so i was unable to store date in Date type in mySql . 
Date format is (yyyy-MM-dd)

```
2013-03-01 > 1200 (This is product quantity) 
2013-03-05 >200 

2013-04-05 > 500 
2013-04-10 > 1000 

2013-05-05 > 850 
2013-05-10 > 50
```

so i want data as

```
for March(2013-03-01 to 2013-03-31) > SUM OF product i.e : 1400. 
April (2013-04-01 to 2013-04-30) > SUM OF product i.e : 1500. 
May (2013-05-01 to 2013-05-31) > SUM OF product i.e : 900.
```

also i have different kind of propducts so i will be getting it according to product , For example purpose consider this records are ONLY FOR Product 'A' of Customer 'XYZ', So please consider this in where clause.

I have tried getting the data month wise using query as follows:

select * from mm_inward Where inward_customerId=1 AND inward_productId=1  ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME(inward_dateofdc) ASC

and i get the data as follows

the date format have changed because I have pasted it from Excel but please keep the date format as mentioned above.

```
Date of deleivery reciept | Company Name | Product Name | Product Quantity
1/3/2013                  |     XYZ      |     A        |     123
2/7/2013                  |     XYZ      |     A        |     1234
3/14/2013                 |     XYZ      |     A        |     120
3/2/2013                  |     XYZ      |     A        |     1500
4/10/2013                 |     XYZ      |     A        |     454
5/1/2013                  |     XYZ      |     A        |     456
6/18/2013                 |     XYZ      |     A        |     1200
```

This is the actual data from my database where i have 2 entries of March

```
3/2/2013 > 1500 
3/14/2013 > 120
```

so i want the sum of it and not differently displaying both the records.

Comment: how you get date in string format? do you recieve as 20041204?

Comment: In this format 2013-03-02

Comment: Using the above data I want to create Graphs for the products inward for the company so I want the sum of selected product month wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use sum and group by clause. Try below and see if it helps. Check for column names.

```
Select sum(inward_prodQuantity), 
   inward_dateofdc,
   inward_customerName,
   inward_productName

from mm_inward
GROUP BY MONTH(inward_dateofdc)
```